# Exception are not getting caught inside method annotate with @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Calling update() from Controller in spring boot annotate with @Transactional and this update() calls update2(). So, when I try to save duplicate values into my database using update2() it don't throw exception to update() instead it goes to Controller method. I want to handle exception in update().

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public String update()
    {
        try 
        {
            return update2();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return "Exception in update()";
        }
    }


    public String update2() throws Exception
    {

        List<Employee> l = repo.findAll();
            for(int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++)
            {
                if(i==0)
                    l.get(i).setUsername("duplicate_value");
                else
                    l.get(i).setUsername("unique_value");
            repo.save(l.get(i));
            }

        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: if you want to catch all exception, then catch (Throwable t)

Comment: Transactions auto committed when execution is about to exit the method which declared transactional. which means in your code, transaction begin to commit when you exit the update method that's why you can not catch this exception in update method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Hadi Moloodi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4232523/hadi-moloodi) mentionied in the comments, your `@Transactional` annotation is what's making your `Exception` not catchable.

You could try to move the `@Transactional` annotation to your `update2` method as follows:

```
public String update() {
    try {
        return update2();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "Exception in update()";
    }
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public String update2() throws Exception {

    List<Employee> l = repo.findAll();
        for(int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++) {
            if(i==0) {
                l.get(i).setUsername("duplicate_value");
            } else {
                l.get(i).setUsername("unique_value");
            }
            repo.save(l.get(i));
        }
        return "success";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Suppose I am having this requirement in which @Transactional is on the update().

Comment: Then there's no sense in catching the exception within `update` method. You can move your try...catch block where your `update` method is called.

Comment: I'm facing the same requirement @KaranSuthar described: inside `update()` method there are several operations that must be inside a transaction.